# How to use formal vector notation to express the simple Pythagorean relation between a velocity vector and its component vectors?

Tags: notation, vectors

I simply want to express the simple Pythagorean fact that I express as follows: If a particle has an instantaneous velocity vector of magnitude 1 and a component vector on the x-axis of magnitude 0.8, then it must have a component vector of magnitude 0.6 on the y-axis.

I'm not sure that "a component vector on the x-axis of magnitude 0.8" makes sense formally or conventionally because I haven't taken a class on vectors, but I thought it was clear enough. I mean (another way of putting it) that the projection of the instantaneous velocity vector (which again has magnitude 1) onto x has length 0.8. Perhaps I need to express it in ijk instead of xyz?

The engineer I'm corresponding with is not accepting the statement, and I don't know why.

Comment: You're saying that if $|(a_1,a_2)|=1$ and $|a_1|=0.8$ then $|a_2|=0.6$.

Comment: Thank you, Snaw!

Answer (score 1):

You can also write, perhaps more acceptable for your engineer buddy.
$$\vec{v}\,\cdot \vec{e_x}=0.8 \hspace{1cm} |\vec{v}|=1 \implies \vec{v}=0.8\vec{e_x}+0.6\vec{e_y}$$
Where  $\vec{v}\,\cdot \vec{e_x}$ denotes the dot product of $v$ with the horizontal direction (the projection part you talked about).